# What is the best layer for chlorophyte farming on terraria mobile?Is it possible on mobile?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I am having trouble getting my chlorophyte farm to work.I am on mobile and an getting ready to fight plantera. I dont even know if it is possible to farm chlorophyte on mobile terraria.Im on the newest terraria update for mobile with x2.5 world size option.No farms seem to work for me for anything.Let me know some farms for other things that work on **mobile**.

Comment: "Chlorophyte Farms" they spawn everywhere in the jungle.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

Building a farm farming isn't the fastest way to get chlorophyte. Just get some spelunker potions and mining potions and dig straight to any chlorophyte you see. Make sure you leave one ore block for every chunk of ore you mine, so it can re-grow.